# Best way to get primary shared directory path in Android 29+

Tags: android, deprecation-warning

I'm working on updating an Android app to remove references to deprecated functions. One feature of the app uses `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to access the primary shared directory of the device. That feature, in context, yields the path `/storage/emulated/0` (and this path is displayed to the user).

As of API level 29, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` has been deprecated and replaced with Context's `getExternalFilesDir()` method, but swapping `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for `getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)` results in the feature yielding the path `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app package name>/files`, which is where app-specific data is stored. If I instead use `getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`, for example, that yields `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app package name>/files/Downloads`. Not the desired result

I've tried appending `/../../../..`, which effectively displays the same directory, but the user ends up seeing `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app package name>/files/../../../..`, and that's unwieldy and annoying. I've also considered simply lopping off everything after and including "Android/", but I don't know if that will cause problems on other devices.

What is the best way to use `getExternalFilesDir()` to get the *primary* shared directory?

Comment: "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() has been deprecated and replaced with Context's getExternalFilesDir() method" -- yes, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated. No, `getExternalFilesDir()` is not a replacement. Google is trying to steer you away from trying to use filesytem paths across all of external storage, which is why they point out `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Comment: "What is the best way to use getExternalFilesDir() to get the primary shared directory?" -- you don't. On Android 10, continue to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. On Android 11+, I would try iterating over the `StorageVolume` objects you get from `StorageManager` and its `getStorageVolumes()` method. For a given `StorageVolume`, you can use `isPrimary()` to get the primary storage volumn and `getDirectory()` to get the filesystem path where it is mounted. Just note that you have limited read/write access to filesystem paths on Android 10+.

Comment: hm, interesting. Thanks for fixing my misconceptions

Comment: In the documentation, however, it does not say that if a file is modified or rewritten via usb your app loses the right to read it ... we are all talking about "paths" but then also once obtained if on android 11 you cannot read or write the files what are you doing? .. well, I still think they have to revise it.

Comment: `What is the best way to use getExternalFilesDir() to get the primary shared directory?` Apart from that you call it a primary shared directory where it is called external storage directory, it is just the path before /Android/... as Android is one of the public directories on external storage.

Comment: But...  If you wanna use external storage then use getExternalStorageDirectory(). On Android 11 you can just list all the directories on it like before 10.